# Gstreamer 1.0 - video compositing

Tags: gstreamer

Dears,

I'd like to create simple picture in picture effect by gstreamer 1.0.

```
>gst-launch-1.0 -e videotestsrc pattern="snow" ! video/x-raw, framerate=10/1, width=200, height=150 ! videomixer name=mix ! autovideosink videotestsrc ! video/x-raw, framerate=10/1, width=640, height=360 ! mix.
```

I am getting "videotestsrc" only and pattern "snow" is not overlayed.

[image]

I assume to get something like:

[image]

Am I missing something in my gstreamer pipeline?

Thank you.

Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

You should get informations about it here: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good-plugins/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-videomixer.html

The good way to do it:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e videomixer name=mix \
    ! autovideosink \
    videotestsrc\
            ! video/x-raw, framerate=10/1, width=640, height=360 \
            ! mix.sink_0 \
    videotestsrc pattern="snow" \
            ! video/x-raw, framerate=10/1, width=200, height=150 \
            ! mix.sink_1
```

Comment: and if you are on Linux or such you can use glvideomixer which is HW accelerated